# In a React app, is <Query> preferred over client.query for executing queries?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am working on a React project where a apollo client is used to performed queries as follows:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

client.query({ query: gql`{ hello }` })
```

But most examples I have seen have looked like:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;

const Dogs = ({ onDogSelected }) => (
  <Query query={GET_DOGS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

      return (
        <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
          {data.dogs.map(dog => (
            <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
              {dog.breed}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

For a React app, when is one method preferred over the other? Is the `<Query>` syntax always preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are use cases for calling `query` directly on the client, but **yes**, using the Query component is the pattern. From the docs:

> When React mounts a Query component, Apollo Client automatically fires off your query. What if you wanted to delay firing your query until the user performs an action, such as clicking on a button? For this scenario, we want to use an ApolloConsumer component and directly call client.query() instead. ... Fetching this way is quite verbose, so we recommend trying to use a Query component if at all possible!

Both the signature of the `Query` component's render prop function and the value the `query` call Promise resolves to are of the type [ApolloQueryResult](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloQueryResult). However, there's some fine differences between the two. For example, using the Component means the `loading` value will be updated multiple times to reflect the status of the query, while you don't get the same functionality when using the client directly.

Generally, using the client directly also means you'll need to persist the results in some other component's state as opposed to just using the values provided by the render props function.

If a query *needs* to be triggered manually, especially if the query results will not be persisted in state, it's perfectly fine to use the client directly. Otherwise, you're probably better off using the `Query` component.